# pandas ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format

Tags: python, pandas

```
df2 = df
df2['Chip Time'] = [x + ':00' for x in df2['Chip Time']]
df2["Chip_Time_mint"] = (pan.to_timedelta(df2['Chip Time']))


df2[['Chip Time']]
```

I am trying to convert a string which is into time format but I get this error ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format, I tried adding '00' but still no luck

Comment: `df2['Chip Time'[:10]]` applies the `[:10]` to the `'Chip Time` string, not the column.

Comment: my bad, I was trying something out with the "df2['Chip Time'[:10]] " code

Comment: Without sample data it's very difficult to add a solution. You can debug this a bit by doing `s  = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Chip Time'], errors='coerce')` Then looking at `df2.loc[s.isnull(), 'Chip Time']` will show you the problematic rows.